# visual studio for mac - installing error: Unable to access "/etc/paths.d/Wireshark" - fix it and try again later please

Tags: visual-studio

When you receive the message "Unable to access "/etc/paths.d/Wireshark" - fix it and try again later please." in a pop up window:
Verify the access rights for Wireshark folder:
$ cd /etc
$ ls -l | grep Wireshark

```
$ -rw-------  1 root  wheel  43 Nov 21  2019 Wireshark
```

Answer (score 0):

FIX => Give access rights:
$ sudo chmod u=rw,g=r,o=r Wireshark

Verify:
$ ls -l | grep Wireshark
$ -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  43 Nov 21  2019 Wireshark

Now you should be able to install visual studio for Mac.